# ncurses LINES and COLS are 0?

Tags: c, ncurses

I am trying to learn ncurses but have hit an odd error. LINES and COLS appear to be set to 0, or else to something that is not an `int`:

relevant parts of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
```

[...]

```
printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n",rand(),LINES,COLS);
blk[i].pos[0] = (int)(rand()/LINES);
blk[i].pos[1] = (int)(rand()/COLS);
```

This outputs:

```
1556162876
0
0
Floating point exception
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At a guess -- not calling `initscr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the ncurses documentation:

> The integer variables LINES and COLS are defined in <curses.h> and will
>          be  filled  in  by  initscr with the size of the screen.

So prior to calling `initscr`, they are probably just 0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as previously mentioned by *Chris Dodd*, prior to calling `initscr()`, their values will be 0. However after calling `initscr()`, their value will be the rows and column of the screen `stdscr` respectively. `getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col)` can also assign these values to the integers `row` and `col`.